# Unable to click on item from 'onclick' partial value even xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Is it possible to click an element through selenium by a partial value of an onclick element? I had try using xpath but it seems not working even on partial value.

There are multiple input items on a page, and I only need to onclick on specific string = 锁定. Kindly advise , Thanks you

HTML:

```
<button class="button_d" onclick="lock('/deposit/ajaxLock.html?oid=12016062862662862','锁定')">锁定</button>
<button style="display:" class="button_d" onclick="depositOk(this , '12016062862662862',53309)">确定</button>
```

MY CODE :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[contains(@onclick, '锁定')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an XPath expert but this CSS selector should do what you ask. It's looking for a `BUTTON` that has an `onclick` attribute that contains the string, 锁定.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[onclick*='锁定']")).click();
```

You could also just look for a `BUTTON` that contains the desired string. The `onclick` string and button text seem to be the same, at least in the example HTML you provided.

Some CSS selector references if you want to learn more...

[CSS Selector reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

[CSS Selector Tips](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors)